# How to use IEnumerable function in shared class accross project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, model-view-controller

I have a common IEnumerable function that I need to use in every controller on my asp,net web mvc application. I have created a SharedClass folder and a public class CommonMethods.

```
using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace LearnWeb.SharedClass
{
public class CommonMethods
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
    {
        // Create an empty list to hold result of the operation
        var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        // For each string in the 'elements' variable, create a new SelectListItem object
        // that has both its Value and Text properties set to a particular value.
        // This will result in MVC rendering each item as:
        //     <option value="State Name">State Name</option>
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = element,
                Text = element
            });
        }
        return selectList;
    }
}
}
```

I have a controller class StockController and I want to use the above common Method inside it. But I'm not able to reference it correctly. Please guide.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using LearnWeb.Models;
using LearnWeb.SharedClass.CommonMethods;

namespace LearnWeb.Controllers
{
public class StockController : Controller
{
/ GET: Stock
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NewStock()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Enter new stock details.";
        var model = new StockModel();
        model.items = GetSelectListItems(items); //trying to call the commonMethods.GetSelectListItems
        return View(model);
    }
 }
```

I have declared both the class and the function as public and added reference but not able to link in the controller class.

Regards,
NewB

Comment: are you getting any compilation error? this line is wrong `using LearnWeb.SharedClass.CommonMethods;` it should be `namespace LearnWeb.SharedClass`

Comment: I tried using using LearnWeb.SharedClass; and on line model.Items = GetSelectListItems(items); I get error The name 'GetSelectListItems' does not exist in the current context. The potential fixes show me to create a method within the same class but I need to use it as common method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the using statement should be:

```
namespace LearnWeb.SharedClass;
```

Just the namespace.  Note that I find the name a bit disingenuous as a namespace should not really contain the word `class`.  Anyway, that aside, your `CommonMethods` class should be marked as `static`:

```
public static class CommonMethods
```

And the method *itself* should be marked as static:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<string> elements)
```

You can then call it like this in your code:

```
model.items = CommonMethods.GetSelectListItems(items);
```

Comment: using static on class and methods solved i :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong `using LearnWeb.SharedClass.CommonMethods;` it should be `using LearnWeb.SharedClass`